# Radius of Convergence of the given series

Tags: real-analysis

We need to find the radius of convergence of the series $\sum a(n)x^n,$ where $a(n) = n^{-\sqrt n}$

The ratio test isn't helping..

Comment: I edited your question so that it looks better. Please try to use mathjax notation for math next time, it will help others to read and perhaps put the effort to answer your question. Also, it might be good to show your calculation when trying to apply the ratio test, because it should work here.

Comment: Did you try Hadamard's formula ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [root test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test)

$$|a_n|^{1/n}=n^{-\sqrt n/n}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}1$$
so the radius of convergence is $R=1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n^{-\sqrt n}}=\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}n^{-\frac1{\sqrt n}}=1$$

since

$$\log n^{-\frac1{\sqrt n}}=-\frac1{\sqrt n}\log n=0$$